# How to share PPTP VPN network in windows 10 to linux in vmware?

Tags: networking, windows-10, debian, vmware, pptp

I have a VPN connection using PPTP on my Windows 10 computer.

I installed Debian in VMWare. Without VPN, I can connect to internet in the VM, but when I turn on the VPN connection, the VM seems to ignore it and connects to the network like usual.

My question is how can I share the VPN connection from my Windows 10 host to the Linux VM?